# Inserting values in a oracle databse using oledb in vb .net, VS 2008

Tags: vb.net, oledbconnection

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim insertOk As Boolean = True
        Dim con1 As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim query As String
        Dim temp As Integer
        con1 = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;Password=sys;User ID=nitishok")

        con1.Open()

        query = "insert into APPLICANTS(APPLICANT_ID,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,SEX,F_H,TOWN,TALUKA,DISTRICT,LANDLINE,MOBILE,BLOOD_GROUP,EDU,DOB) values(:aid,:fn,:mn,:ln,:s,:fh,:tw,:tl,:ds,:land,:mob,:bg,:edu,:dob)"

        cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, con1)

        cmd.Parameters.Add(":aid", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox7.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":fn", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":mn", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox12.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":ln", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox11.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":s", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":fh", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":tw", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox10.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":tl", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox8.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":ds", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox9.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":land", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox5.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":mob", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox6.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":bg", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = ComboBox2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":edu", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = TextBox4.Text

        cmd.Parameters.Add(":dob", OleDb.OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


        If temp > 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Record Added!")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Record Not Added!")
        End If

        con1.Close()
    End Sub
```

im totally new with vb .net. im doing a simple project for my term work.

please explain to me how to insert values.

im getting this errer  ORA-01008: not all variables bound....

im using vb.net VS 2008 
         oracle database 
         oledb connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use question (?) placeholder instead of named parameters because you're using `System.Data.OleDb`. I'd suggest to download ODP.NET -  [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

For instance,

```
query = "insert into APPLICANTS(APPLICANT_ID,FIRST_NAME) values(?,?)"
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar,30).Value = TextBox7.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar,40).Value = TextBox1.Text
....
```