# missing expressing in oracle query through odbc command

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odbc

I am using oracle database as backend .When i run this following script in asp.net c# i got following error

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE YEAR = @YEARS AND SEMESTER = @SEMESTER";
 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YEARS", 2010);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEMESTER", 2);
                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dtf = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dtf);
```

when i run this script i got following error

ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]ORA-00936: missing expression

Whats the problem above code.

Answer (score 0):

`YEAR` is reserved word in `ODBC` try to enclose it inside the square brackets `[]`.

see  [`ODBC Reserved Words`](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/what-are-reserved-access-odbc-and-sql-server-keywords.html)

Try This:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE [YEAR] = @YEAR AND SEMESTER = @SEMESTER";
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YEAR", 2010);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SEMESTER", 2);
            OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dtf = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtf);
```

Comment: OK i changed the parameter name years but still getting error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@` in your query. In Oracle the bind variable as be to like `:BIND_VARIABLE` using colon`(:)`

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE YEAR = :YEAR AND SEMESTER = :SEMESTER";
 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("YEAR", 2010);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SEMESTER", 2);
                OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dtf = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dtf);
```

Comment: i am getting error this error not all variables bound all variable bound

Comment: add `cmd.BindByName = true;`

Comment: Error 1 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand' does not contain a definition for 'BindByName ' and no extension method 'BindByName' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand' could 
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: i am getting error when i type cmd.BindByName = true;

Comment: This [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122243/inserting-values-in-a-oracle-databse-using-oledb-in-vb-net-vs-2008) may help with the new error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to use "?"

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE YEAR = ? AND SEMESTER = ?";
           OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", 2010);
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("whatever", 2); 
           OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
           DataTable dtf = new DataTable();
           da.Fill(dtf);
```

[you can look this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/eg/am/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have tried that

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE YEAR = :YEAR AND SEMESTER = :SEMESTER";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, connection);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":YEAR", 2010);
    //
```

didn't work.